# Перенос Java приложения с базой данных SQLite на другой компьютер

Tags: java, sqlite

Как переносить и запускать Java приложения с базой данных SQLite на другом компьютере?

Нужны подробности:

- Как и где прописывать путь (относительный, абсолютный)?
- Что в каких папках должно находиться?
  и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

При сборке проекта в папку lib будут сложены необходимые библиотеки. Пути Вам в самом коде, при подключении к БД нужно указать. Относительные правильнее. Для переноса на другой компьютер достаточно будет скопировать jar-файл, базы данных и папку lib в одну директорию. Сами базы SQLite обычно хранятся в файлах с расширением "s3db".

Comment: вместо этого    пути  :                                                                                                    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:\\db2\\testDB ";                                                                                 
                                       лучше так указывать    :                                                                                                           String url = "jdbc:sqlite:\\db2\\testDB ";     ???
          
             if (conn==null){                  
               conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
             }